# Associate list with a name

Tags: list, prolog, fact

I have searched all over the internet and on StackOverflow for the answer but I have no idea. I really don't get how to use Prolog and I find it really confusing. I have the solutions in my head but cant write them in Prolog which is very frustrating. I have been stuck in the very first step of my project.

What I need is to state a fact that associates a name with the list so that I don't have to type the list every time I want to do things with it.

for example:

```
list(a, [1,2,3]).
```

then whenever I use `a` in a predicate, the parameter is the list. I have no clue how to do this, I already have a predicate that works when I call it like

```
predicate([1,2,3]).
```

but when I call it with

```
predicate(a).
```

It doesn't work. I think it is not working because it is treating `a` as a parameter that has nothing to do with the list, which is why I want to know if declaring the fact that `list(a, [1,2,3]).`  associates `a` with the list or do I need to do anything else? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an atom, a basic data type, not a variable with the value of your list. Nor is there functional syntax in vanilla Prolog: `a` will never be evaluated and replaced with some other value. If we want a predicate to generate or store a value, we do so by calling the predicate with a variable and binding the variable one of the arguments of the predicate.

If you want to recall list `[1,2,3]`, you'd simply include a fact predicating this list:

```
a([1,2,3]).
```

Then, if you want to query a predicate involving this list,

```
?- a(L), length(L, N).
```

First we unify the variable L with the value determined by predicate `a/1` (meaning 'a which is a 1-ariy predicate'), then we ask for the length of L to be unified with the variable N.

If you wanted to name lists with different designators, as indicated by the `list/2` predicate you wrote above, you could do so, only you'd recall the values in a different way than you're trying. Given these facts,

```
list(a, [1,2,3]).
list(b, [3,2,1]).

?- list(a, X), list(b, Y).
X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = [3, 2, 1].
```

Note: In SWI-Prolog, when interacting with the top-level we can append a `$` to a variable name to recall it's last instantiated value. So if we had already run the above query, we can recall the last value of `L` for other purposes:

```
?- reverse($L, ReversedL).
```

Comment: beware: $L works only for 'small' (unspecified) data structures

Answer (score 1):

You should learn Prolog basic syntax, because it has some fundamental differences WRT other languages. Since you are in for the basic, I don't sell you anything 'magic', but here is an example of a bit of syntax sugar I cooked for  my personal usage.

```
1 ?- [lifter].
% lifter compiled into lifter 0.08 sec, 12 clauses
true.

2 ?- [user].
|: a([1,2,3]).
% user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 2 clauses
true.

3 ?- reverse(a(°),L).
L = [3, 2, 1].
```

The atom `°` it's the 'lifter': the query 3 above get transformed to read

```
?- a(X), reverse(X,L).
```

I don't use often my lifter module, because it makes the code more difficult to debug, and the syntactic gain is rather small...

SWI-Prolog packs offers an alternative (sorry I never used it...): see pack [func](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=func). Is you use SWI-Prolog you can try it by means of ?- pack_install(func).

Comment: That's great! I've been playing around with writing my own functional sugar (just for fun and practice, but also because I don't like the look of the func packs syntax), and I had been going the route of expanding `+func(X)` by calling `func(X,Y)` and  replacing the former with the value of Y. Of course, this only works with "function" predicates which have a final output argument. But I like your notation because, I assume, this will also let you pick any variable to replace the functor? So, e.g., `plus(plus(°,1,2),1, 2).` would be true? I'd be interested to see the code behind your sugar.

Comment: @aBathologist: yes, lifter allows any argument to be lifted. It's an evolution of an initial attempt very similar to your. I'll put it on github, and will post the link.

Comment: @aBathologist: I've loaded it on [github](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets)

Comment: @aBathologist: also, I've added lifter.plt, use `?- ['lifter.plt']. ?- run_tests(lifter).`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to bind your list to a variable. The first is a predefined fact, where the contents of fact 'a' are unified/put into variable 'A' - note variables must start in upper case.

The second way is just by defining the variable containing the list directly, as in 'B' below.

The purpose of the 'useit' predicate below is just to show that the variable can be passed and used.. in this case both lists are displayed.

```
% predefined fact
a([1,2,3]).

useit(MyList) :-
    write(MyList).

declareit :-

    % declare variable 'A' from fact 'a'
    a(A),
    useit(A),

    % Declare B in real time, possibly from prior computation
    B = [3,4,5],
    useit(B).


?- declareit.
[1,2,3][3,4,5]
true.
```